# DIV lado a lado

Tags: css, css3

Como faço para colocar a div galeria do lado direito da div descrição?

HTML

```
<!-- language: lang-html -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <div class="projeto">
                    <h2>DIV TITULO</h2>
                <div class="descricao">
                    <p>DESCRIÇÃO</p>
                </div>
                <div class="box-galeria">
                    <p>GALERIA</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```css
.projeto{
    background-color: #F6F3F3;
    border-radius: 50px;
    padding: 1%;
    margin-right: 5%;
    margin-left: 5%;
    margin-top: 2%;
    border: 5px solid #E5E3E3;
    height: 30em;
}

.projeto h2{
    margin: 1%;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    margin-bottom: 5%;
    border: 1px solid yellow;
}

.projeto p{
    margin: 2%;
    font-size: 1.0em;
    margin-top: 2%;
    margin-bottom: 2%;
}

.projeto .descricao{
    border: 1px solid red;
    width: 50%;
    height: 70%;
}

.projeto .box-galeria{
    border: 1px solid red;
    width: 40%;
    height: 50%;
    position: relative;
}
```

[image: IMAGEM DE COMO ESTA]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fiz uma pequena modificação, adicionando uma div e o style `display:flex` atribuído a ela.

```css
.projeto{
    background-color: #F6F3F3;
    border-radius: 50px;
    padding: 1%;
    margin-right: 5%;
    margin-left: 5%;
    margin-top: 2%;
    border: 5px solid #E5E3E3;
    height: 30em;
}

.projeto-container{
    display: flex;
}
.projeto h2{
    margin: 1%;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    margin-bottom: 5%;
    border: 1px solid yellow;
}

.projeto p{
    margin: 2%;
    font-size: 1.0em;
    margin-top: 2%;
    margin-bottom: 2%;
}

.projeto .descricao{
    border: 1px solid red;
    width: 50%;
    height: 70%;
}

.projeto .box-galeria{
    border: 1px solid red;
    width: 40%;
    height: 50%;
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <div class="projeto">
                <h2>DIV TITULO</h2>
                <div class="projeto-container">
                    <div class="descricao">
                        <p>DESCRIÇÃO</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="box-galeria">
                        <p>GALERIA</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Deu certo! Valeu.